# Koma script captionbeside topbeside alignment question

Tags: captions, koma-script, debugging, scrbook

Code based on the example of scrguien 3.12 (2013-12-19) page 122 gives bad result. Code:

```
\documentclass[captions=topbeside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{captionbeside}
    {A figure description which is neither above nor below, but top beside the figure}
\rule{6cm}{8cm}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the pdflatex result:

[image]

Part of compilation output:

```
> pdflatex topbeside01.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./topbeside01.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
```

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the documented behaviour, so you do not understand or misread the documentation. Read again (emphasis by me):

> With setting `topbeside` the *topmost base lines of the environment contents and caption* will be aligned. […] *In this context it should be known, that the **base line of a pictures*** (sic!) *is mostly at the **bottom of the picture**.* This may be changed, e. g., using `\raisebox`.

And therefore this works as probably wanted (derived from another example in documentation):

```
\documentclass[captions=topbeside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{An Example}
\begin{figure}
\begin{captionbeside}%
{A figure description which is neither above nor
below, but top beside the figure}%
\raisebox{%
\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax
}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}%
}%
\end{captionbeside}
\label{fig:maincls.captionbesidetop}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of example output]

Comment: Obviously I did not understand the doc clearly and missed that I need to use \raisebox.

Comment: @bcsikos: Aaah, OK. Did you get a welcome message? Let me catch on this  (read linked pages): Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You can also see [About TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).